# how to make a slideshow for windows phone 8 app in visual studio 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I am new to Windows Phone Dev. I d like to do a slideshow of for images with swipe gesture in C#, but i cant... The development app is for Win8 in visual studio 2013.

Somebody know a good tutorial or some example to do this?
Cheers!

Comment: Google, there should be enough info about this

Comment: mmmmm no, if had enough information, i would not have asked this question here (I think it's a bit obvious)

Comment: @PhixinEquis Have you looked at the [Panorama control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff941104%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)?

Comment: @PhixinEquis Also, you need to include what research you did in the actual question. It is *not* obvious that you did any research before. Although you are not a new user, I'd recommend taking a look at the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: @PhixinEquis Do you mean the `Pivot` or the `Panorama` control of `WP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the control you are looking for is the **FlipView**

It will work on both Windows 8.1 and Windows phone 8.1

Using it is very simple, add that in your XAML:

```
// SelectionChanged event will be fired every time a picture changes (optional)
<FlipView x:Name="flipView1" SelectionChanged="FlipView_SelectionChanged">
    // Of course replace the source with the relative paths 
    // of the pictures you want to show
    <Image Source="Assets/Logo.png" />
    <Image Source="Assets/SplashScreen.png" />
    <Image Source="Assets/SmallLogo.png" />
</FlipView>
```

This is the simple usage of a FlipView control, but as always it is better to use Bindings and MVVM design pattern, in case you are using it here is what you should write

In your XAML:

```
<FlipView x:Name="Diaporama"
          ItemsSource="{Binding FlipViewImage}">
     <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <Image Source="{Binding}"
                     Stretch="Fill" />
          </DataTemplate>
     </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

And in my ViewModel:

```
// I binded the FlipView with FlipViewImage
// which is a list of strings (each string being a path)
private List<string> _flipViewImage;

public List<string> FlipViewImage
{
   get { return _flipViewImage; }
   set
   {
      _flipViewImage = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged("FlipViewImage");
   }
}

// Then I fill the list
FlipViewImage = new List<string>
{
   // Again replace the image paths with your own
   "../Assets/Seel_photo_Aurelien.png",
   "../Assets/shop_woman.jpg",
   "../Assets/Poster.jpg"
};
```

You now have a slideshow of pictures that you can change with swipe gesture.

I just showed the basic stuff you can do with it, you can find more on the MSDN website or looking in Google

[Msdn documentation for FlipView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh781233.aspx)

Comment: That was i'm looking for, but i cant find the FlipView Control, and show me a markup error (_the name "FlipView" does not exist in the namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"_) because this doesnt exist... do you know how to add it?